How to invest $600K in rental or GIC?
we are an older couple in Canada looking to invest $600K to liveoff. We have no other income for tax purposes.
Should we invest in GICs paying 5.5% or rental with a yield of ~2.5% given current gta market for 1 bedroom (rent:2300, condo fee:475, tax:2000, occupancy: 10 months)

tax + fee is more than the rent, why are you considering this? In any case, when it comes to rentals, you need to remember that you'll spend 1-5% of value on repairs every year, and also need to account for additional expenses (management/insurance/unexpected repairs/appliances/evictions/market moving against you)

Sorry tax is per year while condo fee is monthly

Do you have any experience being a landlord?  Are you aware and comfortable with all of the work and risks it entails? What happens when it goes un-rented for 6 months? What happens when they tear up the walls or break fixtures? What will you do when the hot water heater breaks?
Real Estate investing is not "passive" by any means - if you want to pay someone else to to the "active" work that will eat into your profits as well.
It that's something you want to do it can be very profitable when you include the increase in property value over time, but it's also introduces risks that you don't have to account for in truly passive stock investing.
So if you were to choose rentals over GICs, you are basically saying that the extra return you get from rentals is worth the extra work and risk that comes with it.

Without very much detail provided, I think purchasing GICs is a no brainer.
The best you can hope for in the real estate deal is 1658 per month assuming that the condo is 600K and you purchase with cash.  However, there are many risks involved in this as D Stanley pointed out.  One could use leverage to purchase this condo, but leverage increases risk and you seem to have no room to absorb risk.
If you go with the full 600K in GICs you will receive 2,750/mo.
Is that sufficient for you to live on?
